# rotational matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, machine-learning, apply, matrix-multiplication

I want to achieve an algorithm in R. I cannot start with the code because I am having problem figuring out the problem clearly. The problem is related to rotational matrix, which is actully pretty challenging.

The problem is as follow:

1. The historical data of monthly flows X is transformed into Y by the transformation matrix R where,
           Y = RX                      (3) 
   The procedure for obtaining the transformation matrix is described in detail in the appendix of Tarboton et al. (1998), here we summarize from their description. The transformation matrix is developed from a standard basis (basis vectors aligned with the coordinate axes) which is orthonormal but does not have a basis vector perpendicular to the conditioning plane defined by (3). One of the standard basis vectors is replaced by a vector perpendicular to the conditioning plane. Operationally this amounts to starting with an identity matrix and replacing the last column with . Clearly the basis set in no longer orthonormal. Gram Schmidt orthonormalization procedure is applied to the remaining  1 standard basis vectors to obtain an orthonormal basis that now includes a vector perpendicular to the conditioning plane. 
   The last column of the matrix Y,  , and the R matrix has the property 
   RT = R^(-1). The first   components of the vector   can be denoted as   as the last component is  , i.e.,  . Hence, the simulation involves re-sampling from the conditional PDF ( )

[image: the numerical example of this frame work is presented as an example in the figure]

Comment: I think to get help from SO, you need to reduce the problem to smaller separate questions.  As it stands your question is is not specific enough to a single programming question.

Comment: i just want to know how to construct the matrix "R" (rotational matrix)